# Flutter how to download a file using flutter_downloader package

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i want to download a file using flutter_downloader package i try to use the code in the exemple
of the dowumentation i got a black screen sometimes i got a white screen and i do n't know why i tryed to use only one function of the exemple i have an error and it did not work

```
 import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dart:io';

const debug = true;


class download extends StatefulWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final TargetPlatform platform;

  download({Key key, this.title, this.platform}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<download> {



  String _localPath;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   FlutterDownloader.initialize(
       debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
   );
 
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('bonjour'),
      ),
    body:FlatButton(
    child:Text('bbbbb'),
    onPressed: _requestDownload,
    )
    );
  }



  void _requestDownload() async {
     await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url:'http://barbra-coco.dyndns.org/student/learning_android_studio.pdf' ,
        headers: {"auth": "test_for_sql_encoding"},
        savedDir: _localPath,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true);
  }
```

and i got this exception

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart': Failed assertion: line 73 pos 12: '_initialized': FlutterDownloader.initialize() must be called first
```

i'm asking if there is an explicationn or a solution or a worked exemple with explication and details thank you

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests and the as per the docs you have to initialize before using,

call this

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
FlutterDownloader.initialize(
  debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
);
```

and add this code below in AndroidManifest

```
<provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

check the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) for more

Comment: whereto call it

Comment: you can call it in initState, or just before using

Comment: It works if you have integrated the plugin for each platform correctly.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel vn.hunghd/downloader)   the same probleme

Comment: Ok i will do it

Comment: how to do th android

Comment: I updated my answer, for the future I recommend reading the documentation provided by the plugin developers thoroughly.

Comment: i add this lines in android maifeste.xml but it show me an error C:\Users\HP\Desktop\stage main\akkkk\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: unexpected element <provider> found in <manifest>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216831/discussion-between-henok-and-mohamed-borhene-hamedi).