# How to download video to android phone in flutter from the server by clicking download button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to download video from server to the device storage when clicking the button with progress bar I have is used below code but it is not working fine for me

```
downloadUsingDio(String mediaURL, String fileName) async {
Dio dio = Dio();
await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((appDir) async {
  var filePath =
      await File(appDir.path + '/' + fileName).create(recursive: true);
  var myFile = await dio.download(mediaURL, filePath.path);
  print(myFile);
});
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to download a file using flutter\_downloader package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621900/flutter-how-to-download-a-file-using-flutter-downloader-package)